# swift function to return array index based on name

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code in android java, that randomly return array index based on username. I tried writing same function in swift but no luck.

**Android array xml**

```
<array name="username_colors">
    <item>@color/username0</item>
    <item>@color/username1</item>
    <item>@color/username2</item>
    <item>@color/username3</item>
    <item>@color/username4</item>
    <item>@color/username5</item>
    <item>@color/username6</item>
    <item>@color/username7</item>
    <item>@color/username8</item>
    <item>@color/username9</item>
    <item>@color/username10</item>
    <item>@color/username11</item>
</array>
```

Working example in android

```
 private final int[] mUsernameColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.username_colors);
 
 private int getUsernameColor(String username) {
     int hash = 7;
     for (int i = 0, len = username.length(); i < len; i++) {
         hash = username.codePointAt(i) + (hash << 5) - hash;
     }
     int index = Math.abs(hash % mUsernameColors.length);
     return mUsernameColors[index];
 }
```

My attempt in swift

```
func getUsernameColor(username: String) -> String{
    let colors = [
        "#e21400",
        "#91580f",
        "#f8a700",
        "#f78b00",
        "#58dc00",
        "#287b00",
        "#a8f07a",
        "#4ae8c4",
        "#3b88eb",
        "#3824aa",
        "#a700ff",
        "#d300e7"
    ]
    var hash = 7
    let len = colors.count
    //let len = username.count
    for i in (0..<len) {
        //let scalars = colors[i].unicodeScalars
        let scalars = username.unicodeScalars
        let firstScalar = scalars[scalars.startIndex]
        hash = Int(firstScalar.value) + (hash << 5) - hash
    }
    let index = abs(hash % colors.count)

    return colors[index]
}
```

Comment: "I tried writing same function in swift but no luck." what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
func getUsernameColor(username: String) -> String{
    let colors = [
        "#e21400",
        "#91580f",
        "#f8a700",
        "#f78b00",
        "#58dc00",
        "#287b00",
        "#a8f07a",
        "#4ae8c4",
        "#3b88eb",
        "#3824aa",
        "#a700ff",
        "#d300e7"
    ]
    var hash: UInt32 = 7
    
    for char in username {
        let hashAddition = char.unicodeScalars.first!.value.addingReportingOverflow((hash << 5))
        hash = hashAddition.partialValue.subtractingReportingOverflow(hash).partialValue
    }
    
    let index = abs(Int(hash) % colors.count)
    print(index)
    return colors[index]
}
```

Comment: This `Character` extension is pointless. Why not simply `unicodeScalars.first!.value`? Btw why would you convert the `Character` to `String` if it has `unicodeScalars` property as well?

Comment: I got `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow`